# jQuery select HTML between two string identifiers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I'm trying to make a slideshow of images and all I have is a rich text editor to enter the images and text. So from this html:

```
<h1>title</h1>
<p>description...</p>

<p>#slider</p>

<p><img src="a.jpg" /></p>
<p><img src="b.jpg" /></p>
<p><img src="c.jpg" /></p>

<p>#end-slider</p>
```

How would you select the html between #slider and #end-slider ?

It's a similar concept to extracting text between [link] and [/link] in blog comments e.g.: [link]http://google.com[/link]

Comment: Is `#slider` an ID or text content?

Comment: Not exactly "similar", square bracket `[tags]` can only be parsed by regex - and is usually done server-side for sanitizing (nested tags etc). Now you're presenting actual DOM elements with text nodes, sure you *could* parse them with regex, but there are better ways around that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('p:contains("#slider")').nextUntil('p:contains("#end-slider")')
```

Update:

```
var end = $('p:contains("#end-slider")');
$('p:contains("#slider")').nextUntil(end).andSelf().add(end)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63kQC/

Comment: Thanks this worked well! Also wondering if there is a way to select all of it, so the identifiers and the html i.e. #slider html #end-slider ?

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p:contains("#slider")')
      .nextUntil('p:contains("#end-slider")')
      .wrapAll("<div id='stuff'></div>");
    var required = $('#stuff').html();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/483kL/

Comment: Of course, the `:contains` selector may catch some unintended stuff e.g. `<p>#slider***headkeyboard***dsgdfhdfjdfj</p>`. OP may be ok with that though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('p:contains("#slider")').nextUntil('p:contains("#end-slider")');
});
```